# MSQL export datetime as integer to CSV file

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, export-to-csv

How do we convert a datetime column to integer from MSQL (Microsoft SQL) to a CSV file? For example 20131501101100 to 1923782123

Comment: What is `MSQL` ? MySQL? Microsoft SQL Server? Please update your tags accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a column or in this example the current date an integer:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(s, '19700101', GETDATE())
```

and the other way round:

```
SELECT DATEADD(s, your_column_with_integers, '19700101')
```